# How to convert calling XmlRpc(odoo) to be async in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, odoo, xml-rpc

I have an ASP.NET API project that use C# program and call some XmlRpc as below:

```
XmlRpcRequest requestCreate = new XmlRpcRequest("execute_kw");
requestCreate.AddParams(db, loginDataReturn.uid, passSign, "hra.schedule.time", "ws_get_check_info",
    XmlRpcParameter.AsArray(
        XmlRpcParameter.AsStruct(
            XmlRpcParameter.AsMember("emp_no", queryData.username), 
            XmlRpcParameter.AsMember("check_time", queryData.check_time), 
            XmlRpcParameter.AsMember("isPGY", isPGY)
        )
    )
);

XmlRpcResponse responseCreate = client.Execute(requestCreate);
```

But it had a performance problem with request timeout. So I want to change the code of calling XMLRPC(Odoo) to be async. Does somebody know how to do it?

Comment: Why do you think making the request async will solve the timeout problem?

Comment: I guess the parallel process will solve the neck bottle of each request. But I cannot find the method to call xmlrpc with async.

https://dotblogs.com.tw/wasichris/2017/06/08/101137